# Link text to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have reedited the question as I'm not sure that any of those answers fit.

Here is a code (index.html):

```
<textarea id="myInput1" class="one" name="myInput1" readonly>
One
One
One</textarea>
</div>
```

What do I need:

I need to have another page (text.html), by changing which I will be able to edit this page's text.

So if the page (text.html) will display:
textarea =
Two
Two
Two

The textarea in the (index.html) will also update and change accordingly.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Search and learn it you'll get lot more to explore, it is possible in many methods..

Comment: Thank you for a response. I have tried to search it on my own, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp .  This is very much basic. There are lot more like get data , post data , ect .. based on various Programming language.

Comment: Thank you for providing a path/link where this can be learned. Sorry if it's a basic question, but I have just started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that you need jQuery and more specifically its `load()` function that lets you load data from other pages in the same domain onto another page

**You need include the jQuery library like so:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can use the [`jQuery.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function to get data from another page

```
$("#<parent div>").load(<content id>);
```

---

### Here is a complete example of this:

**index.html**

```html
    <textarea id="myInput1" class="one" name="myInput1" readonly>
        One
        One
        One
    </textarea>
    <p><a href='text.html'>link to next Page</a><p>
```

**text.html:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='content'>
    
    </div>  
    <script>
        $( "#content" ).load( "index.html #myInput1" )
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use ancient and unsupported versions of jQuery.

Comment: None of your approaches load a new page with custom content, they all modify the existing page.

Comment: None of your approaches work at all either, they all depend on `loadNewContent` running to create the element that the user has to click on **before** `loadNewContent` will run.

Comment: They can't click the link because the link won't be added to the page until after they have clicked the link.

Comment: Should i Use an on load event

Comment: No. You seem to have got completely the wrong idea about what the question is trying to achieve.

Comment: I have read the OP's comments and they want the conetnt to be fetched dynamicaly

Comment: No. They want to click on a link, navigate to the page the link points to, and display some custom content on that page which is determined by the link they clicked.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer as best I can and I value your input but it seems we have differnt ideas of what the OP is asking

Comment: You seem to be answering the question "How do I include a navigation bar on every page without copy/pasting it?" which is so very different to what the OP has said that I've no idea how you came by that interpretation.

Comment: they want to get the content from the link on the main page which is exactly what my code does, but again I still value your input but it seems we are understand this question differently

Comment: Hi, sorry I have tried your code and I don't think it works. I want to have two pages, one will be invisible to customers but will contain the text. And I want a second page that will just display the text which is stored at the first page, so if I change the first page's content the second page's content changes too.

Comment: I am so sorry my code didn't work but I have fixed it and it works now

Comment: And @Quentin Thanks for all your help I have gotten it to work without any ancient code

Comment: @TERMINATOR, can you please take a look at the initial question, I have edited it. Maybe you can help me with a script that will include my example?

Comment: @Edvard give me 5 minutes or so

Comment: @Edvard I have adapted my solution to your given code and it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235275/discussion-between-edvard-and-terminator).

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to this.

First you need to make the text you pass to pass available to the page you are passing it to.

The traditional way is to encode this into the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the URL.

```
<a href="mypage?text=One">One</a>
```

Note that this is vulnerable to [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) so if the target page supports **arbitrary** text then third-parties could link to your page and have whatever (e.g. offensive, fraudulent, or defamatory) content they like shown to the person who clicked the link unless you take steps to prevent that.

If you are working with purely client-side JavaScript then you might store it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead. This, however, is subject to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so if someone is clicking around multiple pages and going back to the page showing the link provided content then they'll get the text from then*latest* link that was clicked on, even if that as in another tab.

---

Second you need to read the data from wherever you put it. [This question covers reading query string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) using client side JS.

If you are using server-side JS then you are probably using Express, in which case you can use the [`request.query` property](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

(The earlier link about localStorage shows how to read and write with it).

---

Third you need to insert it into the page. [MDN has a guide for manipulating documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) with client-side JS.

If doing this server-side then you should use a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) that has suitable escaping features to protect against [XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting).

---

Note that having lots of similar pages that differ only by small amounts of data is likely to give you [duplicate content penalties](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content).

Answer (score -1):

You want the page, e.g. index.html, to contain 3 links: one, two, three. After clicking on One it moved to, for example, one.html, and there was a link "return" from href "index.html"?
**Manualy**: `<a href="one.html">One</a>`
In one.html:
**Manualy**: `<a href="index.html">Index</a>`
**Other**
`var element = document.getElementById(id);` In JavaScript.

Comment: Please write me more details!

Comment: <a href="one.html">One</a>, then once the page is opened, "One" text should be displated somewhere on the one.html page without typing it.

Comment: And if I change <a href="one.html">One</a> on the main page to <a href="one.html">One+One</a> it should also change/update on the one.html page accordingly and should display "One+One".

Comment: example: `$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/one/){
    $(".index").show();
  }else{
    $(".index").hide();
   }
});`

Comment: I have given an example of a function that shows a button on the appropriate subpage. Modify to make it fit yourself: D

Comment: @Edvard this answer is not useful?

Comment: I will try it after some time, unfortunately I'm unable to check it right now. But thank you for your response anyway.